# ¿Cómo alinear en la misma altura un input y un button?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con una estructura HTML , es muy simple tengo un input y un botón que quiero alinear uno al lado del otro.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="box2" class="tbox">
            <div id="form_box">
                <input class="tbox" id="subscribe_email" type="text" name="email" value="email address" style="height:25px;padding:14px 19px" />
                <input type="button" value="Enviar" style="height:25px;padding:14px 19px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Entonces en el momento de hacer un padding no consigo que se alineen a la misma altura.

Os updateo el codigo con vuestras respuestas.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        input[type='text'] {
            height: 30px;
            padding:14px;
        }
        input[type='button'] {
          height: 30px;
            padding:14px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="box2" class="tbox">
  <div id="form_box">
    <input class="tbox" id="subscribe_email" type="text" name="email" placeholder='Email address' />
    <input type="button" value="Send" />
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Entonces según las respuestas que leo , el botón es mas pequeño y tendría que ir probando paddings hasta que quedara alineado de verdad , no hay una mejor forma para hacerlo ?

Comment: si fueras mas explicito ayudaría, por que a excepción del css que le quité a tu ejemplo en este enlace puedes ver que se alinean perfecto, entonces cual es el problema exacto por que no queda clro

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hawucakuku/edit?html,output

Comment: Pepe trata de ser más especifico en tus preguntas, realizalas en base a a [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según comprendo, tu lo que quieres es que el botón tenga el mismo tamaño del input de tipo texto, y si este es el caso y quieres que el input y el botón tengan un tamaño más grande, debo decirte que un padding no va a resolver el problema, ya que el padding genera un espacio alrededor del elemento, pero no lo hace más grande en sí. Para hacer que ambos elementos sean más grandes, es recomendable usar la propiedad height de css:

```css
    input[type='text'] {
      height: 50px;
    }
    input[type='button'] {
      height: 55px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="box2" class="tbox">
  <div id="form_box">
    <input class="tbox" id="subscribe_email" type="text" name="email" placeholder='Email address' />
    <input type="button" value="Send" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Déjame saber si tienes alguna otra duda o cambio en tu pregunta para poder aclararte en mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Hola ! A ver si consigo aclarar lo que me interesa , entiendo que si pongo un height me deja la misma altura es decir , si a los dos input les pongo una altura de 25px por así decirlo estará todo en orden , pero en el momeno que pongo un padding (se lo que hace la propiedad padding) el botón siempre se me sube un poquito hacia arriba aunque tengan las mismas propiedades.

Answer (score 0):

Yo considero que la forma mas facil es utilizar flex, entonces en CSS, deberias escribir:

```
#form_box
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;      
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: por defecto están alineados uno a lado del otro, hay qye recomendarle reformule la pregunta pues sus dudas ahora estan entorno a las dimensiones de los inputs